# Json Inside Json Issue in parsing

Tags: jquery, json

I have this code which do not work for inner json

```
$.getJSON("ajax.php?id="+id+"&type="+type, function(json){ 
    json = json[0];
    $.each(json, function (key, val) {
        alert(json.rand_key);   //working
        alert(json.notes);      //not working,inner json
    });
});
```

Here is my fiddle [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rjYyA/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to parse the JSON data once again

```
 var getNotes_inner = this.notes;
 $.each(getNotes_inner, function(id, key) {
     console.log(this.notes);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rjYyA/3/)

I updated

```
alert(json.notes);
```

to

```
alert(this.notes[id].notes);           
alert(this.notes[id].date);
```

And its printing first Notes' comment and date.
Hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass the JSON data once again..you are getting the innerdata anyway as jSON only...that's the issue in your code..i just removed that...please check

```
var g = '[{"id":"552","rand_key":"13934179328867304","ref":"RH-D-552","price":"1000000","agent_1_id":"1","type":"1","deposit":"1000","agent_1_commission_percentage":"2","tenant_buyer_name":"Oscar Tarakjian","commission":"2000","agent_2_id":"16","landlord_seller_name":"Ahmad POA Khalil","deal_date":"2014-02-25","agent_2_commission_percentage":"1","status":"2","deal_estimated_date":"2014-02-27","agent_3_id":"15","sub_status":"2","listings_ref":"RH-R-2627","agent_3_commission_percentage":"3","agent_id":"1","add_info":"My second coments","documents":"","region_id":"1","notes":[{"notes":"My first coment","date":"2014-02-26 11:24:06","user_name":"Admin S"},{"notes":"My second coments","date":"2014-02-27 11:46:35","user_name":"Admin S"}],"listings_unit":"506","listings_beds":"1","renewal_date":"2014-02-28","listings_category_id":"1","area_location_id":"13","sub_area_location_id":"3526","remind_before":"1","strno":"123"}]';
     var getNotes = jQuery.parseJSON(g);

     $.each(getNotes, function(id, key) {

         alert(this.rand_key);//working
         alert(this.notes);

         $.each(this.notes, function(id, key) {
             alert(this.notes);
         });

     });
```